# eclipse not able to download dependencies org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, maven-3, m2eclipse

I am trying to download maven dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3

But eclipse giving me these traces

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:235)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:199)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.execute(OkHttpAetherClient.java:167)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.get(OkHttpAetherClient.java:113)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.resumableGet(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:600)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:453)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:304)
    ... 39 more
```

I am using maven version 3.5. I have checked somewhere. This is due to protocol version error. For the same I have set environment variable -MAVEN_OPTS=Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

I am using eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).

Beside that I have changed in eclipse.ini to point my java location
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\javaw.exe

Now Why protocol version error is coming still. How can I remove this.

I have workaround already. I can use terminal to download dependencies by maven. But As usually I clean up eclipse project. It starts to show me again error.

Beside that There are some XML. Eclipse is showing me errors

```
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://jboss.org/schema/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) 
     the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

If I try to open above url to see XSD. It is there.

edited: Is there any way to know which protocol eclipse is using to download dependencies and which protocol maven is using?

Comment: You should check your configuration cause `Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` this will not work.. `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` should work...Apart from that I strong recommend to get to a new Eclipse version and a newer Java version....

Comment: Eclipse Mars.2 and Java 7 are pretty old and not maintained anymore. E. g. Java 8 supports longer keys than Java 7 (which supports langer keys than Java 6) and which might cause this issue.

Comment: Problem with Eclipse Mars 2. Maven is downloading dependencies on same TLS protocol and running on same java. I see for Java 7. We have only Eclipse Mars. Upper Eclipse version needs support for Java 8. I can't upgrade my project to Java 8 because Spring that we have does not work for java 8. We have spring 3.2.0. To work with Java 8 I need to upgrade my lib for spring 3.2.16 version. As of now What I can try  to run eclipse on java 8 while my project on java 7. If I point eclipse.ini file to pick java8 version to launch while installed JRE libraries I would point out for JDK7.